# A mathematical way to say that the given number is a prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was doing a test on number theory when I encountered this problem-

> What is the value of $n$ for which $n^2+1$ is a prime?
>
> a.$50$
> b.$60$
> c.$40$
> d.$100$

But I am not able to answer this mathematically.

What is a more mathematical approach to the problem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: was this to be done by hand? $50^2+1=41*61$ for example.  A bit hard to eyeball (easy enough with mechanical assistance of course).

Comment: By the way, the correct answer is $c.\;40$,  $100^2+1=73^*137$.

Comment: @lulu-Is there a method to do this without a calculator?

Comment: Well, sure...there are only $25$ primes less than $100$ so even in the worst case (d.) you only have to check $25$ divisions.  I don't see any method faster than brute calculation though.  There are primality tests, of course, which work fine for these examples...but these also require calculators.

Comment: Start with the smallest ($40^2=1601$). Check its divisibility against all primes up to $40$. You can skip $2$ and $5$ of course, since each one of them is a factor of $40$, so it cannot be a factor of $40^2+1$. That comes down to $10$ trials: $3,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37$.

Comment: It is sufficient to check for primes of the form 4k+1, so it is sufficient to check divisibility (for 1601) by 13,17,29,37.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to compute $2^a\pmod{b}$ by repeat squaring.

Assuming that $50^2+1$ is a prime $p$, we must have (by the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)$)
$$ 2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \pm 1\pmod{p}. $$
However,
$$ 2^{\frac{50^2}{2}}\equiv 1844 \pmod{50^2+1}, $$
hence $50^2+1$ cannot be a prime. The same happens for $60^2+1$ and $100^2+1$.

Comment: And how do you compute quickly with paper and pencil?

Comment: @ChristianIrwan: it is kind of tedious but surely possible, since, for instance: $$ 2^{50^2/2} = 4^{5^4} = (((4^5)^5)^5)^5.$$

Comment: I know that it's possible, However, even that is too tedious.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mathemtical methods which you could apply. First one could use an [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) algorithm for $f(n)=n^2+1$, i.e., to factor $f(50)=41\cdot 61$, $f(60)=13\cdot 277$, $f(40)=1601$ and $f(100)=73\cdot 137$. This could be done by hand with some effort.
Secondly one could use a [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). Then we see immediately that only $f(40)$ is prime among the given possibilities. One method to do this by hand is to use a list of smaller primes, up to $\sqrt{f(100)}<101$ and sieving a la [Erathostenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).